# Using Jackson annotations for Swagger

Tags: java, json, spring, jax-rs, swagger

I have a REST API already implemented, which returns a pretty big object with a lot of `@JsonProperty` annotations in it.

 I have seen that Swagger is able to introspectively find the `@JsonProperty`'s and recognize them, instead of adding on top of them the Swagger's `@ApiModelProperty` own annotation (and therefore duplicating annotations), but I am not able to make it work.

 Has anyone achieved this? Is there any workaround?

 I am using Spring, but my API is written using JAX-RS specification.

Comment: What version of swagger are you using?  This should work out of the box, and the latest version is 1.5.7.

Comment: I'm using the version 1.5.6. Maybe I am doing something else wrong.. I'll check.